Creating a Thread Pool to run different instances of a processing function and continuously receive data from a socket
Currently, I have a program that opens a socket and receives a predetermined amount of data. Once that data is obtained, the socket closes, the data is processed, and the output is displayed. Below is the loop that executes this cycle:
while True:
        # Creation of socket with message size 49*2*48000
        # 35 -> # of amplitudes in packet; 2 -> 2 bytes per amplitude
        # 48000 -> Number of 5x5 matrices
        
        sock = FPGASocket(map_row*map_col*2*N) # 5*5*2*2, where 2 is the number of seconds recorded
        sock.connect(host, port)

        # Socket set to receive data
        data = sock.myreceive() 

        # frombuffer takes the received data (from socket_test)
        #   and puts it into an array, viewing the data as 16-bit ints rather than
        #   unsigned 8-bit ints. The reshape function then takes the created array
        #   and turns it into a 96000x5x5 data cube (-1 serves as a "fill-in" number
        #   as the program can tell how the elements divide into a 5x5 size. So, since
        #   the matrix size is 5x5 (x, 5, 5), it can tell that the total message length
        #   will be able to fit into 96000 layers. This means
        #   that 5*2*96000 implicitly chooses the number of matrices).
        cube = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16).reshape(-1, map_row, map_col) 
        print(cube.shape)

        # Close socket
        print("Socket closing")
        # sock.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        sock.sock.close()
        sock = None
        
        feature_maps = extract_features(cube, map_row, map_col, power_threshold, 
                                        feature_type[0], feature_params_mfcc, sample_rate, 
processes)

        confidence_matrix = classify(feature_maps, model_path, map_row, map_col)

        vis(confidence_matrix, fig, axis)

All of the methods within the loop work correctly and do exactly as I want them to. However, it can only process one data cube at a time and closes the socket, meaning a socket is continuously opening and closing. So, I would like to use a thread pool or other multithreading tools to run multiple of these processing cycles at once while leaving the socket open to continuously receive and process data. Below is a diagram that hopefully illustrates what I'm hoping the solution to achieve, assuming near constant processing time.
Bar Timing Diagram showing the alignment in time of the socket and data processing threads
So, how would this solution be coded?
Thanks, and let me know if I need to explain anything else.
As a side note, I have attempted looking into the Concurrents library and the ThreadPoolExecutor subclass, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it, or even if it is the correct approach.
